# Problem in integration of JSF1.2 & Spring Security

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I am implementing spring security in my JSF 1.2 project.This deployed successfully in JBoss 5.0.1 but it gives me following exceptions when I try to access login page of my application

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FacesContext must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContextUtils.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(FacesContextUtils.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.getWebApplicationContext(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.getBeanFactory(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:79)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:50)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
```

From this trace I am guessing that some how spring beans trying to use faces context before it initializes.

Following is my project structure :

```
MyEar
|-- lib\ (contains all spring security jar files)  
|
|
|-- myWar
       |-- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (entries for spring security jars)
       |
       |-- WEB-INF
               |-- applicationContext.xml 
               |-- lib\ (local jar files jsf,facelets etc)
```

Here one thing is important to mention is that I want all my spring securities jar in ear's lib directory and this exception is not happening when I put all my spring securities jar directly under ear (earcontent) not in lib.

Please suggest me whether this is the issue with structure of my project of something else?

**UPDATE**:Here is my manifest content:

```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Class-Path: lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar 
   lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar 
   lib/org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/spring-security-taglibs-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar 
   lib/spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

here is some part of web.xml entries:

```
        <!--  Delegating to a Spring-managed bean that implements the Filter interface -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBean</param-name>
        <param-value>filterChainProxy</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you post your `MyEar/myWar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: I have updated the post with manifest content

Answer (score 2):

The `FacesContext` is created by the `FacesServlet`. So when it is `null`, then it means that you didn't invoke the `FacesServlet`. You need to ensure that the browser request URL matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as you've definied in your `web.xml`.

If it is for example

```
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
```

then you need to ensure that you invoke the login page as

> http://localhost:8080/myWar/login.jsf

and thus **not** as

> http://localhost:8080/myWar/login.xhtml

Comment: yes balusC I am also thinking the same and i have similar entries in my web.xml as you can see in my update section of my question post.My browser invoking the http://localhost:8080/myWar/security/login.jsf only.

Comment: Hey @BalusC any comments I have updated the question with more info

Comment: Well, this seems to be more a Spring specific issue, than a JSF specific one. I'm sorry, I am not familiar with Spring.